# How to hide div ID from URL

Tags: url, html, url-rewriting, hide

I need to know a way of hiding or stop automatic addition of the div id from the url. 
ex:- when I click the link which directs to inline division 'contact', my url in the browser shows http://mysite.com/index.php#contact

instead i want it to be shown as only http://mysite.com/index.php, even when i click that link. i hope i made the question clear. thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: it's not a div id, it's an anchor which helps to navigate and bookmark, then why you are looking to remove?

Comment: @sogeek — And those anchors are created by adding an id to an element, which can be a div.

Comment: @Quentin, oops, i don't know why i had a wrong thought, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment identifier is handled entirely client side, it never gets passed to the server, so you cannot use URL rewriting to conceal it.

Your options are:

- Link to the document itself instead of the specific element.
- The above plus add JavaScript so *any* visitors to the page will be scrolled to that div
- Move the div to the top of page
- Live with it. It can't be leaking any secret information.

Comment: thanks. i just can't live with that. it makes the whole url look fuzzy :(

Comment: URLs are tools, not works of art. People don't look at them unless they need to get information from them. It doesn't matter if they "look fuzzy".

Comment: Okay then. I'll live with that! Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/index.php#contact">Contact</a>
```

Change it to

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/index.php">Contact</a>
```

If the anchor tag is set by some JS-framework, you'll need to find out what library or JS-code is causing this and disable that.

Comment: No, just as @so_geek said, it's a simple anchor. I wanna know a way to hide it. and still the link should go to the relevant anchor point. (without showing the anchor name in the address bar.)